Mediatr different handler response depending on boolean flag?
In my controller I want to return two different responses depending on includeUsers boolean. The problem is my handler right now returns a BuddyResponse dto, and I want it to return BuddyResponse dto or BuddyWithUsersResponse dto. How do I change handler and/or its return type so it returns what i want depending on includeUsers flag? Or should I create two different handlers but then I would also need to check in controller action which one query send to mediatr?
Code:
public class Buddy : Entity
{
    public User User { get; private set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; private set; }
    public User MatchedUser { get; private set; }
    public Guid MatchedUserId { get; private set; }
    public DateTime MatchDateTime { get; private set; }
}

public record BuddyResponse(Guid Id, Guid UserId, Guid MatchedUserId, DateTime MatchDateTime)

public record BuddyWithUsersResponse(Guid Id, UserResponse User,UserResponse MatchedUser, DateTime MatchDateTime)

[HttpGet("{userId:guid}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserBuddies(Guid userId,bool includeUsers = false)
    {
        var query = new GetUserBuddiesQuery(userId, includeUsers);

        var buddiesResult = await mediator.Send(query);

        return buddiesResult.Match(
            Ok,
            Problem);
    }

public record GetUserBuddiesQuery(Guid UserId) : IRequest<ErrorOr<List<BuddyResponse>>>;

GetUserBuddiesAsync from repository returns Buddy depending on includeUsers flag btw.
public class GetUserBuddiesQueryHandler(IBuddiesRepository buddiesRepository, IMapper mapper)
    : IRequestHandler<GetUserBuddiesQuery, ErrorOr<List<BuddyResponse>>>
{
    public async Task<ErrorOr<List<BuddyResponse>>> Handle(GetUserBuddiesQuery query,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var buddies = await buddiesRepository.GetUserBuddiesAsync(query.UserId, query.IncludeUsers);

        return mapper.Map<List<BuddyResponse>>(buddies);
    }
}

I tried to create a base class for both responses but I can't return for example BuddyResponse when return type of handler is BaseBuddyResponse. I tried to create a wrapper object:
public class BuddyResponseWrapper
{
    public List<BuddyResponse>? BuddyResponses { get; set; }
    public List<BuddyWithUsersResponse>? BuddyWithUsersResponses { get; set; }
}

but in my controller response i would get json with both where one of them is always null so i would also need to add some logic in controller.
